# Concatenating string as names for dataframe subsets

Tags: r, string, dataframe, subset

in R I have a list of input files, which are data frames.

Now I want to subset them based on the gene given in one of the columns.
I am used to do everything repetitively on every sample I have but I want to be able to make the code smoother and shorter, which is giving me some problems.

How I have done it before:

```
GM04284 <- read.table("GM04284_methylation_results_hg37.txt", header = TRUE)
GM04284_HTT <- subset(GM04284[GM04284$target == "HTT",])
GM04284_FMR1 <- subset(GM04284[GM04284$target == "fmr1",])
```

How I want to do it now:

```
input_files = list.files(pattern = "_methylation_results_hg37.txt")

for (file in input_files){
  # Define sample and gene from input file
sample = strsplit(file, split = "_")[[1]][1]

# read input
data = read.table(file, header = T, na.strings = "NA")
  # subset input into gene specific tables
paste(sample,"_HTT", sep = "") <- subset(data[data$target == "HTT",])
paste(sample,"_FMR1", sep = "") <- subset(data[data$target == "fmr1",])
}
```

The subset part is what is causing me problems.
How can I make a new variable name that looks like the output of paste(sample,"_HTT", sep = "") and which can be taken as the name for the new subset table?

Thanks in advance, your help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need to create new variable for each dataframe? If you're going to treat them all in the same way later, it might be better to use something more uniform and better organized.
One alternative is to keep them all in the list:

```
input_files = list.files(pattern = "_methylation_results_hg37.txt")

res_list <- list()

for (file in input_files){
  # Define sample and gene from input file
  sample = strsplit(file, split = "_")[[1]][1]
  
  # read input
  data = read.table(file, header = T, na.strings = "NA")
  
  # subset input into gene specific tables
  res_list[[paste0(sample,"_HTT")]]   <- data[data$target == "HTT", ]
  res_list[[paste0(sample,"_FMR1")]]  <- data[data$target == "fmr1",]
}
```

Then you can address them as members of this list, like `res_list$GM04284` (or, equivalent, `res_list[['GM04284']]`)

Comment: Hi Vasily, the list seems like a good idea but it only takes values from column 1. I would like to have the whole table saved. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Normally it should be all columns. It's hard to tell without having actual data what is wrong. Can you share couple of those files? (don't need the whole file - first 10 or so  lines is enough)

Comment: Here is an example file: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1cFXwewAu7CvBqXiBoDvpwUOk106A_t3utSOD2T5rHhc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: oh sorry, I have changed the permission now.

Comment: my bad, I forgot double brackets in the assignment part. Corrected now, check if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Vasily makes a good point in the answer above. It would indeed be tidier to have each dataframe contained within a list.

Nonetheless, you could use `assign()` if you really wanted to create a new dynamic variable:

```
assign(paste0(sample,"_HTT"), subset(data[data$target == "HTT",]), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: assign() seems like a great option as well, but when I have all these new tables how can I then call the specific ones without writing out the names for all the samples?